# Custom editors for Expression Blend

Tags: expression-blend

Expression Blend comes with a bunch of editors for colors, gradients, collections, etc. Is it possible to extend expression blend to support a custom editor? For example, one might to have a custom editor for existing types such as TimeSpans or a completely new types.

I can't find anything on msdn but I can't find any discussion about it either - so I basically just want my expectation confirmed that this isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is in line with your question directly but you can set value property editing in your behaviors etc. if that's what you're looking for.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.propertyediting%28VS.100%29.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb548204(v=vs.100))

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514507%28VS.100%29.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb514507(v=vs.100))

Comment: The links surely answer my question - this is where it's documented, in the "Visual Studio" documentation. Thank you very much.